# AHK V2 How to call a function on the click event for a button

Tags: function, user-interface, autohotkey

I want to call a function whenever a button on my Gui is pressed, the code is as follows:

The ultimate idea of this is to open the gui when a window appears
Add Check Boxes
Add Button
User Checks Boxes and clicks button
text in array for checkboxes in array gets typed out int a field in the window.

`

```
MyGui:= Gui()    
myGui.Title := "Test"; ;Gui Name    
MyBtn_Click() ;Function to be called when button pressed
{
    msgBox("Pressed Button")    
}    
myBtn := MyGui.AddButton(,"OOK") ;Adds an ok Button to the Gui
myBtn.OnEvent("Click", MyBtn_Click(*)) ;Call the function
myGui.Show() ;Shows Gui
```

`
Now the problem is when I try to call the function my button click it gives me a syntax error. I've tried to make sense of how to define a function and how to call it, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the asterisk in the function definition (see [variadic functions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Functions.htm#Variadic)) and then remove the parentheses in the second `OnEvent` parameter.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

MyGui:= Gui()    
myGui.Title := "Test" ;Gui Name    
MyBtn_Click(*) ;Function to be called when button pressed
{
    msgBox("Pressed Button")    
}    
myBtn := MyGui.AddButton(,"OOK") ;Adds an ok Button to the Gui
myBtn.OnEvent("Click", MyBtn_Click) ;Call the function
myGui.Show() ;Shows Gui
```